# Encrypt the connection string in web config

Tags: asp.net

I need to encrypt the connection in webconfig

`<add name="Stay" connectionString="Data Source=WIN-04;Initial Catalog=stay123;uid=sa;password=sql2008; Max Pool Size=100; Connection Timeout=60" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>`

I have to decrypt and use while fetching the data from database

Comment: So what is the problem ?

Comment: Look at this article http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/795135/Encrypt-ConnectionString-in-Web-Config

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dx0f3cf2(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Where can i encrypt my connection strings

Comment: http://www.aspdotnet-suresh.com/2011/11/encrypt-and-decrypt-configuration.html

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/795135/Encrypt-ConnectionString-in-Web-Config